# How to connect more than two databases in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, sql-server-2008

I want connect to 3 databases. I don't have any problem if i connect just two databases. When i try to connect 3 databases. i have problem like i cant connect to database two.

this my config at database.php :

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => '192.168.11.29,1433',
'username' => 'userhsp',
'password' => 'hsp432@',
'database' => 'HSP',
'dbdriver' => 'mssql',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => TRUE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => FALSE,
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);

$db['crm'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => '192.168.11.29,1433',
'username' => 'userhsp',
'password' => 'hsp432@',
'database' => 'CRM',
'dbdriver' => 'mssql',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => FALSE,
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);

$db['pltapol'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => '192.168.11.29,1433',
'username' => 'userhsp',
'password' => 'hsp432@',
'database' => 'pltapol',
'dbdriver' => 'mssql',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => FALSE,
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

and in my model like this :

```
private $db2;
private $db3;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->db2 = $this->load->database('crm', TRUE);
    $this->db3 = $this->load->database('pltapol', TRUE);
}
```

i just can get object from database **pltapol**, but i dont get object from **crm**. how to fix it?

Comment: `$this->db2->query('YOUR QUERY');` and `$this->db3->query('YOUR QUERY');` but also make sure to change `'pconnect' => TRUE` in default to false

Comment: I try to change all database 'pconnect' to false then i can't connect to all database. other suggestion?

Comment: Check this https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to answer my question. i tried to use

```
$this->db2->db_select() or $this->db3->db_select()
```

if i want to use that connection before `$this->db2->query() or before $this->db2->query()`

that is work!

happy coding :)